# Why do alkyl substituents stabilize alkenes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, enthalpy, stability

My textbook states that because $sp^2-sp^3$ bonds are stronger than $sp^3-sp^3$ bonds, alkenes are more stable than alkanes. The rule given is that bonds with more $s$ character are stronger.

However, it then states that an alkene with more alkyl substituents at the C=C double bond is stronger than an alkene with just hydrogens attached around the double bonded carbons. Carbon $sp^2-1s$ Hydrogen bond is stronger than Carbon $sp^2-sp^3$ Carbon bond. So how can my textbook use bond strength to explain why the alkyl substituted alkene is more stable than the non-substituted alkene?

Comment: If your understand hyperconjugation in MO theory, you may want to see this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/20362/44877

Comment: @TanYongBoon thank you. yes this is perfect response! was confused how hyperconjugation applied to case of alkenes vs carbocations

Comment: @TanYongBoon Btw, your profile is very impressive for a HSer. do you have plans of US college and PhD in chemistry in future?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour). Since you are new here, I advise you to go through the [policies of our community](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). I don't want to sound mean but comment section is not for friendly chatting. I suppose, you have already found what you are looking for. If you have any further doubts, feel free to comment or edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Does stackexchange have a chat function?

Comment: Of course it has, check *The periodic table*

Comment: @ebehr He means https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table, but you'll need 20 rep to chat.